# Determining when a two-finger map drag occurs on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to work around the issue where a map is just part of the page, and on a mobile if you scroll down to the map, it fills the screen and you can't scroll the page anymore - you scroll the map instead.

so I changed the draggable option to have two finger map scrolls. This works.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', { 
   center: [latitude,longitude],
   zoom: 17,
   layers: [streetmap], //default layer
   dragging: !L.Browser.mobile, tap: !L.Browser.mobile //twofinger map controls, one finger page scrolling
});
```

But I want to still have the map auto-follow the player, unless they have deliberately dragged the map away (and then a button to snap back to automove).  The code of relevance for that stuff is here:

```
var panbtn = L.easyButton({
  states: [{
    stateName: 'pauseAutoMove',      
    icon:      'fa-sign-in fa-lg',               
    title:     'Centre display at current Player', //Tooltip
    onClick: function(btn, map) { //if you click the button whilst it is in pauseAutoMove, recentre map and unpause
      currentAutoMove = true; //Set flag, that currently map is being moved to recentre
      mymap.panTo([latitude,longitude]); 
      currentAutoMove = false; //Remove flag again    
      pauseAutoMove = false; //set flag to stop Auto moving map 
      panbtn.state('AutoMove');                               
    }
  },{
    stateName: 'AutoMove', //clicking the button once it is doing AutoMove does nothing
    icon:      'fa-crosshairs fa-lg',
  }]
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on("zoomstart", function (e) { currentAutoMove = true }); //Set flag, that currently map is moved by a zoom command
mymap.on("zoomend", function (e) { currentAutoMove = false }); //Remove flag again
mymap.on('movestart',(e)=>{ //Check if map is being moved
    if(!currentAutoMove){ //ignore if it was a natural PlayerLoc or programmatic update
        pauseAutoMove = true; //set flag to stop Auto moving map 
        panbtn.state('pauseAutoMove'); //change button style to remove crosshairs and have a arrow-in icon
    }
});
```

and elsewhere

```
function updatemap() {  // Update the current player location on map
    playerLoc.setLatLng([latitude,longitude]); //update current player marker instead of creating new ones
    
//other stuff goes here to update too

    if(!pauseAutoMove){ //pan the map to follow the player unless it is on pause
            currentAutoMove = true; //Set flag, that currently map is moved by a normal PlayerLoc Auto update
            mymap.panTo([latitude,longitude]); 
            currentAutoMove = false; //Remove flag again
    };
        mymap.invalidateSize(); //reset map view
}; // end updatemap
```

Now that I have two-finger map-dragging, on the mobile, it does NOT register the change of state to panbtn. The map snaps back again and I can't stop it now. (Still works as intended on a PC screen).

So, my question: It seems `mymap.on('movestart',(e)=>{...` is NOT being triggered by a two-finger drag? Is there a way to re-enable that?

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet events for touch interaction, including touch zoom (which is what happens when you use 2 fingers, even just for panning) are `"touchstart"`, `"touchmove"` and `"touchend"`.

However, these events will likely fire even with 1 finger touch, so you may need to add a check similar to Leaflet TouchZoom hamdler: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.7.1/src/map/handler/Map.TouchZoom.js#L68

So you could combine with what you have with something like:

```js
function mayDisableAutomove() { //Check if map is being moved
    if(!currentAutoMove){ //ignore if it was a natural PlayerLoc or programmatic update
        pauseAutoMove = true; //set flag to stop Auto moving map 
        panbtn.state('pauseAutoMove'); //change button style to remove crosshairs and have a arrow-in icon
    }
});

mymap.on('touchmove', (e) => {
  if (!e.touches || e.touches.length !== 2) { return; }
  mayDisableAutomove();
});

mymap.on('movestart', mayDisableAutomove);
```

Comment: that sure looks like it should work for me .... but no :-(   The `mymap.on('touchmove', (e) => ` is not getting triggered by a finger move ... even tried `mymap.on('dragstart', (e) => ` since I am requiring movement to be done with two fingers. No difference.

Comment: My bad sorry, it seems that I mixed Leaflet map events and native document events. You could attach the touchmove listener on the document instead, probably adding some checks to ensure the touch started on the map container. Then a better solution could consist in customizing the Leaflet touchZoom handler instead.